# Environment variables in docker when exec docker run

Tags: linux, docker

I've got a problem with environment variables in docker.
When I run command:

```
$ docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c "echo $HOME"
```

I've got response:

```
/Users/bylek
```

But when I run:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and then:

```
root@5e079c47affa:/# echo $HOME
```

I've got:

```
/root
```

Second response is correct. Why first command return $HOME value from my host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo $HOME` is being evaluated on your host because you haven't got the syntax of the switch to bash correct. It's Linux so you need single quotes.

Try replacing your double quotes with single quotes.

eg. This is what I get:

```
bash-3.2$  docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```