# Use container environment variable in docker run without using bash -c

Tags: bash, docker, debian, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have a WP-CLI container where I have to run the following command:

`wp --allow-root core config --dbname=$MYSQL_DATABASE --dbuser=$MYSQL_USER --dbpass=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --dbhost=$WP_CLI_MYSQL_HOST --debug`

When I run in bash inside container, I have no problem, but when I try to do:

`docker-compose run --rm wordpress-cli --rm core config --dbname=$MYSQL_DATABASE --dbuser=$MYSQL_USER --dbpass=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --dbhost=$WP_CLI_MYSQL_HOST --allow-root --debug`

All environment variables are evaluated in the host instead of the container, so they are passed empty to container.

I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791107/environment-variables-in-docker-when-exec-docker-run), that using `bash -c 'my command'` will do the trick, but my `ENTRYPOINT` is the WP command, so I want to just run without using the `bash` command.

Answer (score 3):

Just escape the `$` so they get passed through to the container:

```
docker-compose run --rm wordpress-cli --rm core config --dbname=\$MYSQL_DATABASE --dbuser=\$MYSQL_USER ...
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, container runs '$MYSQL_DATABASE' as a string, dollar sign doesn't work inside container

Comment: You still have to use bash to interpret those variables. There's no way around running `bash -c` in that case.